# Should I add ETag for all APIs

Tags: http, nginx, etag

Is ok to add `Etag` for all APIs (GET)? Is common scenario or not?
I am considering to add `ETag` for all apis so that can reduce the network traffic. But it will need to implement the hash computing on backend so the server's loading will increase a little bit. That's the props and cons I can think of now.

API for `Types`, `Charts`, `member informcation`...

BTW, I use `NGINX` as my webserver to serve the `ASP.NET Core web API` run behind `Kestrel` server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think hash computing is something to worry about, especially so if you cache it somewhere.

If you're still worried you can use a different HTTP validator, like `Last-Modified` header.

Comment: Yes, don't worry about the hash computing so I don't know why not every website's API implement the Etag. Do I miss anything

Comment: You don't miss anything. I would say it's *them* missing to implement it :)

Comment: Compare the hash computing and network traffic, I will choose the hash computing so I think I need to add this for all APIs(get)?

Comment: If I add the ETag for all GET APIs I think the traffic will only 1/100 before add it